# Dreamweaver regexp positive look behind error

Tags: regex, dreamweaver, lookbehind

I'm getting a `syntax error` and `invalid quantifier` error in `dreamweaver` when I try to use a regexp in the source code.
The purpose is to find spaces in front of numbers on table cells and delete them.

```
(?<=>)\s+(?=\d)
```

this expression works on notepad++ but not in dreamweaver.

Can this be a Dreamweaver bug or the syntax is wrong?

Of course I can make a text search looking for `>\s` and replace by `>` but then I cant catch more spaces than the ones specified in the search string

thanks in advance

PS: Would be nice also to have a multisearch option in the dreamweaver search screen, to run multiple search and replace in one operation, like code clean up. An extension maybe?

Comment: Many tools don't support look arounds - are you sure dreamweaver is not one of them?

Comment: Well reading this [article](http://www.adobe.com/cn/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/regular_expressions_pt1.html) and [part 2](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/regular_expressions_pt2.html). There is no mention of lookaround, so maybe dreamweaver really doesn't support it. Anyways, I **hate** dreamweaver.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use DW but, since I have read several posts about lookarounds problems with DW, I assume that DW doesn't support these regex features.

You can use capturing groups instead (if DW supports it!):

```
search :  (>)\s+(\d)
replace:  $1$2
```

or

```
replace: \1\2
```

Answer (score 0):

To append to the previous answer, when formulating a replace statement in DreamWeaver, use the format of $1 rather than ^1 for the variables.

I receive a similar "invalid quantifier" response in DreamWeaver CC 2015.1 when using a negative lookbehind: 
    `(?<!somephrase)`